# PostgreSQL - how to return the last X values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume that in database are these values:

**time_column**

```
2013-03-02 19:00:00
2013-03-02 20:00:00
2013-03-02 21:00:00
2013-03-02 22:00:00
```

I need to get the last 3 records include with the value from a row, which is in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_column =< '2013-03-02 22:00:00' LIMIT 3
```

This query returns these rows (no `22:00:00`):

```
2013-03-02 19:00:00
2013-03-02 20:00:00
2013-03-02 21:00:00
```

But I need to get these ones:

```
2013-03-02 20:00:00
2013-03-02 21:00:00
2013-03-02 22:00:00
```

But how to do that?

Thank you

**EDIT:** There is a way to get the needed rows on the application layer, but if would be possible to get that from a sql, that would be great.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the compared value not being included - that's just an artifact of the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_column =< '2013-03-02 22:00:00'
ORDER BY time_column DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Oh, I need a vacation! My question looks like I just came to the computer for the first time... However, thanks Marlin.